# A multiplicative property of the Euler totient function $\phi$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, multiplicative-function

How can I show that if $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then

$$ \phi(ab)= {\phi(a) \phi(b) d \over\phi(d)} $$

I know I have to use the fact that 
$$\phi(m)=  m \cdot\prod_{p|m} (1-\frac1p),$$  where the $p$ ranges over all the distinct primes of $m$.

Comment: divide by $d$ and use that $\phi$ is multiplicative

Answer (score 1):

Hint : If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then there is no prime $p$ dividing both $a$ and $b$.

Consider the prime factors of $a\cdot b$ and locate the corresponding factors of $\phi(a\cdot b)$ (they either belong to $\phi(a)$ or to $\phi(b)$)